Get a list of slack channels that a given user have posting rights to
The conversations.list Slack API returns all the channels that a user can visit. However, how can I get list of channels that a given user has posting access to ?
Tried the 'types' param in this api: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list But there are no options to filter the result to only include the channels the user has posting access to.
